# set icon for nodes in XMLTreeView via XML-File (vb.net)

Tags: xml, treeview

I´m not a professional in vb.net, but i try to make a tool for my colleague and me.
I got a XMLTreeView on my form and i load a XML-File in it.
Now, I want to set each node in the XMLTreeView another icon, but it must set by the XML-File.

This is my XML-File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Nodes>
  <Node Text="Programme" Icon="BlaBlub.ico">
    <Node Text="Test" Icon="C:\MyProgramm\Icons\icon2.ico">
      <Programm Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual" & _
        "Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe">Visual Studio</Programm>
      <Programm Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft" & _
      "Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE">Excel</Programm>
    </Node>
    <Node Text="andere" Icon="C:\MyProgramm\Icons\23.ico">
      <Programm Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual" & _
        "Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE">VB.NET</Programm>
    </Node>
    <Node Text="Test1" Icon="Huhu.ico">
      <Programm>bla</Programm>
      <Programm>blup</Programm>
    </Node>
  </Node>
</Nodes>
```

I created on my form an ImageList too.

How can i set the icon for each node? I think it has to be dynamically. But I don´t know no how to do this...
(I don´t want to load all Icons to the ImageList manually)

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.imagelist.aspx

Comment: Do you use WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Comment: I use WinForms.